# Site buga todo quando hospedado

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou aprendendo front-end e fiz um site usando bootstrap aqui, resolvi subi-lo em algum lugar grátis pra começar a brincadeira e pra minha surpresa ele está com alguns problemas.

A impressão que eu tenho é que ele não está identificando o bootstrap, mas eu coloquei tudo lá. Ai eu não sei se é porque o host é ruim ou porque eu não coloquei no lugar correto.

[Clique aqui para entrar no Meu Site](http://www.andreyhartung.qlix.com.br/) ***Obs: Diminuam o tamanho do navegador pra ver os bugs***

Como ele deveria ter ficado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: http://www.andreyhartung.qlix.com.br/css/bootstrap.min.css: `404 not found`

Comment: Teu site não está achando o css do bootstrap, conforme comentário o bfvaretto. Dá uma verificada se você colocou o arquivo lá mesmo, e se o mesmo é acessível.

Comment: -_- ter deft de atenção é foda viu ¬¬ eu estava a mais de uma hora procurando o erro -_-"  Obrigado pela ajuda mano!